# Sending BigDecimal using intent get and put on android

Tags: android

I am trying to send a bigdecimal number from my main app to the widget.
Currently, it is set up as a float and works like this:

```
float Current = intent.getFloatExtra("Current", 0);
```

Is there a way to do it for BigDecimal for example?

```
BigDecimal current = intent.getBigDecimalExtra("Current", 0)?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. One alternative may be pass as String and covert it back to BigDecimal in other activity.

Answer (score 13):

Since BigDecimal is Serializable and putExtra is overrided with many value types, but none is BigDecimal. Compiler fits with Serializable value version method.

[Android Intent put extra Serializable value](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable))

You can bring back your data just using:

```
BigDecimal current = (BigDecimal) intent.getSerializableExtra("Current");
```

Don't forget casting the returned value to BigDecimal.